Angular 18 generic class does not see interface function
I am kind of new to Angular and I try to implement a generic table component, that will display me a table of any model I send it. It works as it should but then I decided to implement interface that will add custom labels instead of model property names.
Im trying to access it via the method return Object.keys(data[0]).map(key => data[0].getMappedLabel(key) || key);
But instead I get an error that data does not have a method getMappedLabel().
Here is my generic class ts
import { Component, Input, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { CustomLabels } from '../interfaces/custom-labels.interface';

@Component
({
selector: 'app-generic-table',
templateUrl: './generic-table.component.html',
})
export class GenericTableComponent\<T extends CustomLabels & Record\<string,any\>\> implements OnInit
{
@Input() data: T\[\] = \[\];

displayedColumns: string\[\] = \['test','test1','test2'\];
dataSource!: MatTableDataSource\<T\>;

constructor() {
}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.displayedColumns);
        this.displayedColumns = this.getColumns(this.data);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
    }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
if (changes\['data'\] && changes\['data'\].currentValue) {
this.displayedColumns = this.getColumns(this.data);
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
console.log(this.dataSource)
console.log(this.displayedColumns)
}
}
getColumns(data: T\[\]): string\[\] {
if (data && data.length \> 0) {
return Object.keys(data\[0\]).map(key =\> data\[0\].getMappedLabel(key) || key);
}
return \[\];
}
}

Its html
<table mat-table \[dataSource\]="dataSource"\>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns" matColumnDef="{{column}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ column }} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[column] }} </td>
        <td>kutas</td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

The line I call generic component
         <app-generic-table [data]="key.value.taskImport"></app-generic-table>

and the model I have with interfaces
import { CustomLabels , LabelMap} from '../interfaces/custom-labels.interface'
export class ExcelImport implements CustomLabels{
Project: string;
Type: string;
WorkerName: string;
WorkerCompany: string;
Day: Date;

    constructor(project: string, type: string, workerName: string, workerCompany: string, day: Date) {
      this.Project = project;
      this.Type = type;
      this.WorkerName = workerName;
      this.WorkerCompany = workerCompany;
      this.Day = day;
    }
    private labelMap:LabelMap={
      Project: 'Projekt',
      Type: 'Typ',
      WorkerName: 'Imię i nazwisko',
      WorkerCompany: 'Firma',
      Day: 'Dzień'
    }


getMappedLabel(key: string): string {
return this.labelMap\[key\] || key;
}
}
export interface LabelMap{
\[key:string\]:string;
}

export interface CustomLabels{
getMappedLabel(key:string):string;
}

I am confused since when I tried calling my model and calling a method on it directly, not via generic component I got it working. Like key.value.taskImport[0].getMappedLabel() 

Maybe your data is not an instance and then you can't use getMappedLabel().

You are right. I didnt even know that was the case in TypeScript, that I can have something of type but not instantiated. Did my research and after creating instance of data after recieving it, the code works as it should be. Thank you!
